# Custom Event Not being Dispatched AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, events, custom-events, event-dispatching

I have a class "Shop" through which I'm trying to dispatch an event. Previously, I've done with another class "Buyer" and it works but the same thing doesn't work for my new class.

Function of Shop Class that is dispatching event:

```
        public function Select(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(ShopName);
            dispatchEvent( new SelectEvent(SelectEvent.SHOPSELECT,null,this));


        }
```

The code when I run it , displays the "Shop Name" efficiently through `trace` but it doesn't seem to dispatch the event or else, it is dispatched but not reccieved well.

Reccieving code for Shop class dispatched event:

```
addEventListener(SelectEvent.SHOPSELECT,shopselected,true);
```

Buyer Class' function where the same method worked:

```
    public function Select(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(buyerCode);
            if(y>=377|| enteredmall)
            {
                dispatchEvent( new SelectEvent(SelectEvent.BUYERSELECT,this,null));
            }

        }
```

Recceiving Code for the Buyer Class dispatched event:

```
addEventListener(SelectEvent.BUYERSELECT,showselectbuyer,true);
```

This works but Shop class' one doesn't.

The only difference between both the classes is that the `CLICK` is on different objects. The Buyer class's object when clicked dispatches the event but the Shop Class's movieclip when clicked dispatches the event.

I've learnt about bubbling of events and I think I'm doing it right in the code.  I've read similar question that was asked here but I couldn't understand how to proceed with the solution as the answer was not clear to me.

How to make it work for the shop class as well?

Additional Information:

Select Event Class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
    public class SelectEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const BUYERSELECT:String = "buyerselect";
        public static const SHOPSELECT:String = "shopselect";

        public var selectedbuyer:Buyer;
        public var selectedshop:Shop;



        public function SelectEvent(type:String, selectedbuyer:Buyer=null, selectedshop:Shop=null, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
            if(selectedshop==null)
            {
                this.selectedbuyer= selectedbuyer;
            }
            else
            {
                this.selectedshop= selectedshop;
            }


        }

        override public function clone():Event
        {
            return new SelectEvent (type, selectedbuyer, selectedshop ,bubbles, cancelable);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I can't exactly understand what are you trying to do but If you are trying to listen for propagating event the object that is dispatching the event must be added to the display list and also have the bubbles parameter in the constructor of the event set to true

Comment: Please post the SelectEvent class.

Comment: @nikolayn the Event does not have to bubble. Using the capturing phase would allow listening for the Event effectively in the same way as if it was a bubbling event. It has to be on the display indeed.

Comment: @null I have added the SelectEvent Class.

Comment: The event is dispatched for sure since you are calling that method yourself. What you mean is that it is not being caught. The only reason I can think of right now is that the Shop object is in a different display list.

Comment: @BotMaster thanks a lot. I figured out it was actually in a different display list. If it were posted as an answer I would have chosen it as the best answer. It works well now.